# How to share a member of the form in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

How do I make a value retrieved from a form object available to another class. 
Lets call this class `Sample.java`. How do I make the values submitted from the
JSP `form` available to class `Sample.java` and keep it there for use until the user logs out.

I tried adding a public String variable in Controller method shown below and then creating an instance of Controller in Sample.java to get the value but it always returns a `null`.

```
 @RequestMapping( value = "abc/xyz/dummyPath.html", method = RequestMethod.POST )
    public String processThisValue( @ModelAttribute( "myValues" ) MyBean myBean,
            ModelMap model)
    {

        log.info("I am in my controller.........");  

        String valuePassed = myBean.getValuePassed();

        log.info("Prints fine here: " + valuePassed);

        return "";
    }
```

Comment: I don't see `Sample` class in your code but what you are trying to do is not possible unless you save the object into session or serialize and deserialize it when you need.

Comment: Hi gigadot, Sample.java is just a regular class with couple of methods in it. Do you think session would work here? Can we pass a variable from a servlet(controller) to a regular class using session?

Comment: I have trouble understanding what you mean by passing to a class here. If an object is created within the controller method then yes, you can use session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution come in two parts:

1)

> and keep it there for use until the user logs out.

You can use a Session scoped bean to hold the value.

2)

> how do I make the values submitted from the JSP form available to class Sample.java

The Controller stores the Submitted value in that session bean. The Simple.java class (hopefully) a bean too, access that bean to get the value.

(I have no IDE at the moment, so I need to scribble it a bit)

```
@Component
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_SESSION)
public class MySessionBean()

  private String content;

  Getter/setter
}

@Controller
...

   @Autowire
   private MySessionBean mySessionBean;

   ...
   public String processThisValue( @ModelAttribute( "myValues" ) MyBean myBean,
        ModelMap model) {
     //myBean is only a simple class!!!!!
     ...
     this.mySessioBean.setContent(valuePassed);
     ...
   }


@Service
public class Sample() {

  @Autowire
  private MySessionBean mySessionBean;

  public void doSomething() {
     System.out.println("the current users value:" + mySessionBean.getValue());
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Httpsession to set your user session inside your Spring MVC Controller

```
public String processThisValue( @RequestParam("value") String value, HttpSession session
        ModelMap model) {

         MyBean.setTheValue("value");
         session.setAttribute("key", MyBean);
         return "somepage";


   }
```

@Scope session annotation is nice but once your controller got too big then it can cause some scaling issue. I prefer the old tedious HttpSession :)